# Do I really have to HOLD the super key in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity-2d

I am switching to 2d and it's looking good.  But it seems like I can't do my usual <kbd>Super</kbd>+... combinations.  For example, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't do anything.

It's running much faster and I'm really pleased with that.  There are a couple of things that don't seem to work so well, however.  If I want to switch between running applications (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) nothing happens - it just opens the dash!  It seems I have to hold super down for half a second before I press <kbd>2</kbd>.

I don't mean to be picky, but half a second delays adds up to quite a lot in a full day's working.  Is there any way to get this instant like in 3d?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: It's not supposed to be like that. You should consider [filing a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+filebug) if this problem still occurs, after having installed all the latest updates.

Comment: This problem the user is facing has still been resolved - Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/834078

Answer (score -2):

If you have installed `compizconfig-settings-manager` (Type in the terminal `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` to install it), then type into the search filter `Unity`, and click on the Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

Where it says "Key to show the launcher", you can change that key from Super to Super+, thus reserving the Super key for other application usage.